# nginx Reverse-Proxy: using stream module for passthrough and reverse proxy

Tags: nginx, proxy, passthrough, stream, nginx-reverse-proxy

I use the stream module in order to passthrough tls traffic where I cannot reverse proxy, e.g. because I dont have the certificate (local 3CX install) or it breaks stuff (ssl vpn with client cert).
I then forward the "rest" to a different IP on the same host (127.0.0.1) for reverse proxying.
The problem was the the remote_addr was not always 127.0.0.1 and there seemes to be no way to set the "real" remote address.
To circumvent this I enabled the proxy_protocol and used $proxy_protocol_addr.

However this breaks all passthrough websites and I have not found a way to conditionally enable the proxy_protocol only for the "default"

I do all this so I can match on sni and use a single IP for all websites.

I am not hung up on doing it exactly this way, if anyone has an idea how to achieve this in a different/better way, I am all ears.

```
stream {
  map $ssl_preread_server_name $targetBackend {
    3cx.example.com  192.168.1.2:443;
    vpn.example.com  192.168.1.3:443;
    default  127.0.0.1:443;
  }
  server {
    listen 192.168.1.100:443;
    proxy_connect_timeout 1;
    proxy_timeout 3s;
    resolver 192.168.1.1;
    proxy_protocol on;
    proxy_pass $targetBackend;
    ssl_preread on;
  }
```

so... how to make the proxy_protocol conditional (afaik if just does not work in stream context) or solve it another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you need to install a frontend for `3cx` and `vpn` that decodes PROXY protocol and converts it to HTTP requests for the actual webserver.

Another option is to have separate nginx instances for web services and proxied protocols.

Comment: No, this does not work, I tried this but it seems to take it literal and wont resolve the variable :-(

Comment: Then I guess you need to install a compatible proxy in front of `3cx` and `vpn`, which decodes the PROXY protocol and forwards requests to the websites.

Comment: so basically one stream proxy with proxy_protocol on which then forwards to another stream proxy which listens to proxy_protocol and then forwards without proxy_protocol?
Would that work? Is this the easiest solution? sounds kind of workaroundish

Comment: Yes, that is workaroundish, but since conditional `proxy_protocol` doesn't seem to be possible, then it is one way. Another way is to have run two separate nginx instances, the other one handling websites and other one the proxying.

Comment: ok, thanks. it looks like although this is workaroundish it is the only solution?
if anyone knows a better solution feel free to post, until then I will mark this as the solution. thanks again
Actually... I noticed the "answer" is in the comments not the answer...
Maybe you can post a new answer or edit your current one?

Comment: I updated the answer.